# how to do the validation of content page using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

hii all
this is my master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="OfficeApps.master.cs" Inherits="master1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />
  <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/ui.jqgrid.css" />
  <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/ui.multiselect.css" />

  <script src="JS/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="JS/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="JS/hoverIntent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="Styles/MasterStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title></title>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">


<div>
    <table class="mastertable">
        <tr>
            <td class="masterheader">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


                    <div class="logo">
                        <asp:Image ID="image2" class="logo1" src="Images/OfficeApps.png" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="menubar">
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </div>
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="mastercontent">

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

              <div class="divbutpos">

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="LOGOUT" OnClick="Button1_Click" BackColor="#00CCFF"
        BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Underline="True"
        ForeColor="White" Style="cursor: hand" />
    <%-- <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1"  CssClass="divbutpos" OnClick="Button1_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/signout.JPG" runat="server" />--%>
   </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>

            <td class="masterfooter">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

**the reason i posted my entire masterpage is that it has multiple contentplaceholders in a table format.....**

my content page looks like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/OfficeApps.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="UsersGrid.aspx.cs" Inherits="UsersGrid" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">

<div class = "scroll">

    <div id="searchbox" title="SearchBox" class="SearchBox">
        <div class="SearchBoxHeader">
            <h2 style="text-align: center; color: #2E6E9E;">
                SEARCH</h2>
        </div>

        <asp:Label ID="lbl_FilterStatus" runat="server">Status: </asp:Label>  <asp:DropDownList
            ID="dl_FilterStatus" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">Active</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">InActive</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_FilterUname" runat="server">Username: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox
            ID="tb_FilterUname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_FilterSname" runat="server">Shortname: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox
            ID="tb_FilterSname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/search_icon.gif"
            ImageAlign="AbsBottom" OnClientClick="return searchuser();" />
    </div>

<table id="usergrid">
</table>

<div id="pager1" style="text-align: center;">
</div>

</div>

<div class="divlblpos">
        <asp:Label CssClass="welcomelogo" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Welcome"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="welcomelogo"></asp:Label>
</div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="Hf_SelectedID" runat="server" />  


<div id="dialog" title="UserDetails" style="display: none;">

    <table  cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="10px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_usrnm" CssClass="popuptxt" runat="server" Text="UserName"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Tb_UserName" Height="15px" Font-Size="13px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

         <td>
                <asp:Label ID="unameerror" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_name" CssClass="popuptxt" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Tb_Name" Height="15px" Font-Size="13px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_shortnm" CssClass="popuptxt" runat="server" Text="ShortName"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Tb_SName" Height="15px" Font-Size="13px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Admin" CssClass="popuptxt" runat="server" Text="IsAdmin"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Cb_Admin" Checked="false" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Active" CssClass="popuptxt" runat="server" Text="IsActive"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Cb_Active" Checked="false" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Email" CssClass="popuptxt" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Tb_Email" Height="15px" Font-Size="13px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_phone" CssClass="popuptxt" runat="server" Text="Phone"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Tb_Phone" Height="15px" Font-Size="13px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_mob" CssClass="popuptxt" runat="server" Text="Mobile"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Tb_Mobile" Height="15px" Font-Size="13px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Depts" CssClass="popuptxt" runat="server" Text="Departments"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:ListBox ID="Lb_Departments" Font-Size="13px" DataTextField="DepartmentName"
                    Width="154px" DataValueField="DepartmentID" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                </asp:ListBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_App" CssClass="popuptxt" runat="server" Text="Applications"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:ListBox ID="Lb_Applications" DataTextField="ApplicationName" Font-Size="13px"
                    Width="154px" DataValueField="ApplicationID" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                </asp:ListBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Sup" CssClass="popuptxt" runat="server" Text="Supervisors"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:ListBox ID="Lb_Supervisor" DataTextField="UserName" Font-Size="13px" Width="154px"
                    DataValueField="UserID" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Lb_Success" Font-Size="10px" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>                    
                <asp:Button ID="Button_Edit" Width="150px" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClientClick="return edituser();" />                    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

my problem is when i have to validate using the below code inside the contentplaceholder validation is not being done
the code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">


     $.validator.addMethod("regex",function(value, element, regexp) 
            {
                var check = false;
                var re = new RegExp(regexp);
             return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
            },"<p style='color:red'>*Please check your input</p>");



        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#aspnetForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%=Tb_UserName.UniqueID %>: {
                        minlength: 5,
                        required: true,
                     regex: "^[a-zA-Z0-9'.\\s\]{3,15}$" 

                    },
                    <%=Tb_Name.UniqueID %>: {
                        minlength: 5,
                        required: true,
                    regex: "^[a-zA-Z0-9'.\\s\]{3,15}$" 
                    },
                    <%=Tb_SName.UniqueID %>: {
                        required: true,
                    maxlength:4,
                    regex: "^[a-zA-Z0-9'.\\s\]{1,4}$" 
                    },
                    <%=Tb_Email.UniqueID %>: {
                     required: true,
                    regex:"^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
                    },
                    <%=Tb_Phone.UniqueID %>: {
                        minlength: 8,
                        maxlength: 8,
                        required: true,
                    regex:"^[0-9\s]{8}$"
                    },
                    <%=Tb_Mobile.UniqueID %>: {
                        minlength: 10,
                        maxlength:10,
                        required: true,
                        regex:"^[0-9\s]{10}$"
                    }
                }, 
                messages: {
                    <%=Tb_UserName.UniqueID %>:{ 
                        required: "Please Enter your username", 
                        minlength: "User name must be atleast of 5 characters" 
                    },
                     <%=Tb_Name.UniqueID %>:{ 
                        required: "Please Enter your name", 
                        minlength: "name must be atleast of 5 characters" 
                    },
                     <%=Tb_SName.UniqueID %>:{ 
                        required: "Please Enter your shortname", 
                      maxlength:"Shortname cant exceed 4 characters"
                    },
                     <%=Tb_Email.UniqueID %>:{ 
                        required: "Please Enter email", 

                    },
                    <%=Tb_Phone.UniqueID %>:{ 
                        required: "Please Enter phone", 
                      minlength:"phone number should have 8 digits",
                      maxlength:"phone number should have 8 digits only"
                    }, 

                <%=Tb_Mobile.UniqueID %>:{ 
                        required: "Please Entermobile number", 
                        minlength: "mobile number should have 10 digits"
                        maxlength:"mobile number should have 10 digits only"
                    }
                    }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I sure hope you're validating on the server also

Comment: no server side validation @ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the asp.net validators, they do the same thing you're trying to do, PLUS server side validation!

- RegularExpressionValidator(can also be used for min and max length)
- RequiredFieldValidator

Server side validation is a must because javascript can always be disabled or modified by the user.